# How to handle resource limits for apache in kubernetes

Tags: apache, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy a scalable web application on google cloud. 
I have kubernetes deployment which creates multiple replicas of apache+php pods. These have cpu/memory resources/limits set.

Lets say that memory limit per replica is 2GB. How do I properly configure apache to respect this limit?

I can modify maximum process count and/or maximum memory per process to prevent memory overflow (thus the replicas will not be killed because of OOM). But this does create new problem, this settings will also limit maximum number of requests that my replica could handle. In case of DDOS attack (or just more traffic) the bottleneck could be the maximum process limit, not memory/cpu limit. I think that this could happen pretty often, as these limits are set to worst case scenario, not based on average traffic.

I want to configure autoscaler so that it will create multiple replicas in case of such event, not only when the cpu/memory usage is near limit.

How do I properly solve this problem? Thanks for help!

Comment: I think it is possible to create autoscaler based on custom metrics (which i could get from the apache insides) but this seems pretty obscure. I think there must be better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend doing the following instead of trying to configuring apache to limit itself internally:

- Enforce resource limits on pods. i.e let them OOM. (but see NOTE*)
- Define an autoscaling metric for your deployment based on your load.
- Setup a namespace wide resource-quota. This enforeces a clusterwide limit on the resources pods in that namespace can use.

This way you can let your Apache+PHP pods handle as many requests as possible until they OOM, at which point they respawn and join the pool again, which is fine* (because hopefully they're stateless) and at no point does your over all resource utilization exceed the resource limits (quotas) enforced on the namespace.

---

* NOTE: This is only true if you're not doing fancy stuff like websockets or stream based HTTP, in which case an OOMing Apache instance takes down other clients that are holding an open socket to the instance. If you want, you should always be able to enforce limits on apache in terms of the number of threads/processes it runs anyway, but it's best not to unless you have solid need for it. With this kind of setup, no matter what you do, you'll not be able to evade DDoS attacks of large magnitudes. You're either doing to have broken sockets (in the case of OOM) or request timeouts (not enough threads to handle requests). You'd need far more sophisticated networking/filtering gear to prevent "good" traffic from taking a hit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But isn't it a bad practice to let pods OOM intentionally ? How do I figure out proper resource limits for pods in this case if not request_count * max_mem_per_request + overhead?

Comment: re: OOM being bad practice - you'd usually not want your pods to OOM during normal operation, but if you're under DDoS, there's little point in trying to fence against that, so it's fine to let pods OOM away and let kubernetes worry about keeping your capacity up. Unless you find this setup actually detrimental in practice, I wouldn't advise trying to come up with something more complex (However, do monitor the number of OOM kills in your monitoring system).

Comment: re: resource limits, whatever makes sense for your use case is "proper". `request_count * max_mem_per_request + overhead` is a fine. Alternatively, you can set it to a size that is a multiplicative factor (GCD) of the CPU/Mem available on your nodes, so that you can have better bin packing, in the cluster. At the end of the day, resource quotas serve two purposes: (1) prevent a rouge entity from wrecking everything else running on the cluster (2) acting as scheduler hints/values to improve cluster-wide resource utilization, and reduce contention for resources.

Comment: Thanks. I'll mark this as an answer. Though I'm not sure how to size pod resource quotas properly.

Comment: @JanImrich Your resource quotas will evolve over time as you understand your workload and your cluster utilization better, but for starters, you can pick some fraction of your host machines' resources. For example, if you have a 24core, 128G machine, you can allocate 4CPU/21G per pod. You can go smaller or higher based on what a single pod needs, so you likely want to continuously measure your pod, node and cluster utilization and then adapt to minimize wastage. I can't give you better advice without knowing your exact setup and looking at the utilization numbers.